# Find derivatives of $f(x)$ defined as an integral

Tags: integration

A function $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, $g(1)=17$ and $\int_0^1g(x)dx=34$.

Assume that $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^x(x-t)²g(t)dt$

How do I prove that $f'(x)=x\int_0^xg(t)dt-\int_0^xtg(t)dt$
and how do I calculate $f''(x)$?

I'm kind of new to this type of problem and I'm a little bit clueless.

Comment: Do you know the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\begin{array}\\
f(x)
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^x(x-t)²g(t)dt\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^x(x^2-2xt+t^2)g(t)dt\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\int_0^xx^2g(t)dt-\int_0^x2xtg(t)dt+\int_0^xt^2g(t)dt\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}x^2\int_0^xg(t)dt-x\int_0^xtg(t)dt+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^xt^2g(t)dt\\
\text{so}\\
f'(x)
&=\frac{1}{2}(x^2\int_0^xg(t)dt)'-(x\int_0^xtg(t)dt)'+\frac{1}{2}(\int_0^xt^2g(t)dt)'\\
&=\frac{1}{2}(x^2g(x)+2x\int_0^xg(t)dt)-(x^2g(x)+\int_0^xtg(t)dt)+\frac{1}{2}(x^2g(x))\\
&=x^2g(x)+x\int_0^xg(t)dt)-x^2g(x)-\int_0^xtg(t)dt)\\
&=x\int_0^xg(t)dt-\int_0^xtg(t)dt\\
\text{differentiating again}\\
f''(x)
&=xg(x)+\int_0^xg(t)dt-xg(x)\\
&=\int_0^xg(t)dt\\
\end{array}
$